# 1 CSS property is overridden by a shorthand

Tags: css

```
 .btn-default {
        color: #fff!important;
        background: #303f9f!important;
        border-color: #303f9f!important;
        border-color: #ccc;
        border: 1px solid;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #5e5e5e;
       -moz-border-radius: 3px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #f9f9f9), #f9f9f9;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #f9f9f9), #f9f9f9;
    background: linear-gradient(#fefefe, #f9f9f9), #f9f9f9;
    border-color: #c3c3c3 #c3c3c3 #bebebe;
```

I've got the following error:

`".btn-default: "border"` resets `border-color` property set earlier"

I need to know where it is overridden. pls help me

Comment: this `border-color: #303f9f!important;` doesnt look right, dont u need a space before `!important`?

Comment: @TheFlash it works without space too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tells you exactly where it is overridden:

> ".btn-default: "border" resets border-color property set earlier"

When you set `border`, it resets `border-color`.

On line 4 you set `border-color` and then on line 6 you set `border`. Since you don't specify a border-color on line 6, it gets set to the default. (That is how shorthand properties work).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using ! important by deleting the undesirable code. And if need be be more specific - border-color: instead of border: etc.

```
background-color: #303f9f;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #f9f9f9), #f9f9f9;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #f9f9f9), #f9f9f9;
background-image: linear-gradient(#fefefe, #f9f9f9), #f9f9f9;

/* border-color: #303f9f!important; delete this line if it is not the desired colour - don't double up on your code */
border-color: #ccc;
```

Comment: or put that `!important` after `#ccc` instead?

Comment: @Abbr !important should be used very judiciously and only in cases where you can't tidy up your code to avoid it's use. Sometimes it can't be avoided, like when working in some areas like wordpress where it is needed to over write a css statement of a plugin stylesheet.